# How to get list of activated and deactivated module using some script from database?

Tags: 7

How to show list of activated and deactivated module using some script from database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For disabled modules:
SELECT * FROM `system` WHERE `type`='module' AND `status`=0

For enabled modules:
SELECT * FROM `system` WHERE `type`='module' AND `status`=1

If you need to do this using drupal functions, you can try something like:

```
    $query = db_select('system', 's')
    ->fields('s', array('name', 'weight'))
    ->condition('type', 'module')
    ->condition('status', 0);
    $result = $query->execute();

    foreach ($result->fetchAll() as $record) {
      // do something here...
    }
```

And process the results from $result.

Comment: while using  SELECT * FROM system WHERE type='module' AND status=0 i am getting name of only one deactivated module,and your query throwing syntax error

Comment: I updated the db_select query and tested the code to be sure it's working. It now returns a list of disabled modules.

Answer (score 0):

After you install/enable the [Forena](https://www.drupal.org/project/forena) module (Disclosure: I'm a co-maintainer), you can use one of the reports that's delivered with it. I.e. the ***Enabled Modules and Themes*** report in category "Drupal Administration", which you can find at `reports/drupaladmin.enabled_contributions`.

If you don't like the report (eg you neem more or less data (columns) to be shown, just tune the report (using a WYSIWYG report designer) and/or adapt the related SQL query (using a WYSIWYG query builder). So no custom (PHP) code ivolved.

And if you want to save (export) the format, pick whatever fits for you, such as CSV, PDF, XML, JSON, MS Excel, MS Word, ...